# Copy the content of one HTML table into another using JavaScript Revisited

Tags: javascript, html, html-table, copy

I'm teaching myself JavaScript and I need to copy one table into another. I've been able to reproduce @Gushiken's [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/771571/copy-the-content-of-one-table-into-another) and @Quentin's [response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/771571/copy-the-content-of-one-table-into-another) with this example:

HTML:

```
<button onclick="copytable()">Copy Table</button>

<br />
<br />

<table id="TableA">
    <!--<tbody></tbody>-->
</table>
<br />

<table id="TableB" style="border:solid">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td id="col1">Column 1</td>
            <td id="col2">Column 2</td>
            <td id="col3">Column 3</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Data a</td>
            <td>Data b</td>
            <td>Data c</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<br />
```

JavaScript:

```
function copytable() {
  var source = document.getElementById('TableB');
  var destination = document.getElementById('TableA');
  var copy = source.cloneNode(true);
  copy.setAttribute('id', 'tableB');
  destination.parentNode.replaceChild(copy, destination);
}
```

But once Table B is copied, how do I access elements within the reproduced table? i.e., Table B is "hardcoded" HTML while ... is Table A in memory? I'd like to change Column 1 to Column A, Column 2 to Column B, etc. after the table copy event.

Also, how do I delete the copied table?

Comment: try using an inspector, you'll see what's going on.

Comment: You are dealing with a document. The fact that some parts were created from HTML and some from DOM APIs doesn't make any difference to functions playing with the bits. It's all in memory.

Answer (score 0):

To delete the old TableB you can try `source.outerHTML = "";`

Then to delete the object: `delete(source);`

About to insert TableB inside tableA I did not understand.
Do you want to insert like `<tableA><tableB></tableB></tableA>`,
or you want move only the `<td>`s of the TableB?

Answer (score 0):

Since you have applied a new id to the copy, you can use that to access the cloned element.

```js
function copytable() {
  var source = document.getElementById('TableB');
  var destination = document.getElementById('TableA');
  var copy = source.cloneNode(true);
  copy.setAttribute('id', 'tableA');
  destination.parentNode.replaceChild(copy, destination);
}

function deletCopy() {
  var el = document.getElementById('tableA');
  el.innerHTML = '';
}
```

```html
<button onclick="copytable()">Copy Table</button>
<button onclick="deletCopy()">Delete Table</button>

<br />
<br />

<table id="TableA">
  <!--<tbody></tbody>-->
</table>
<br />

<table id="TableB" style="border:solid">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td id="col1">Column 1</td>
      <td id="col2">Column 2</td>
      <td id="col3">Column 3</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Data a</td>
      <td>Data b</td>
      <td>Data c</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<br />
```

But the problem with accessing the elements within the new table is, since you have ids for inner elements of the clone, you have multiple elements with the same id. If you can use class instead of id for the `td` elements then

```js
function copytable() {
  var source = document.getElementById('TableB');
  var destination = document.getElementById('TableA');
  var copy = source.cloneNode(true);
  copy.setAttribute('id', 'TableA');
  destination.parentNode.replaceChild(copy, destination);
}

function deletCopy() {
  var el = document.getElementById('TableA');
  el.innerHTML = '';
}

function changeCopy(){
  var el = document.getElementById('TableA');
  el.querySelector('.col1').innerHTML = 'Column A';
  el.querySelector('.col2').innerHTML = 'Column B';
  el.querySelector('.col3').innerHTML = 'Column C';
}
```

```html
<button onclick="copytable()">Copy Table</button>
<button onclick="deletCopy()">Delete Table</button>
<button onclick="changeCopy()">Update Table</button>

<br />
<br />

<table id="TableA">
  <!--<tbody></tbody>-->
</table>
<br />

<table id="TableB" style="border:solid">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td class="col1">Column 1</td>
      <td class="col2">Column 2</td>
      <td class="col3">Column 3</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Data a</td>
      <td>Data b</td>
      <td>Data c</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<br />
```

Answer (score 0):

To delete the source table, you can do:

```
var tableB = document.getElementById('TableB');
tableB.parentNode.removeChild(tableB);
```

And you can change the reproduced table right after you copied it, e.g:

```js
function copytable() {
  var source = document.getElementById('TableB');
  var destination = document.getElementById('TableA');
  var copy = source.cloneNode(true);
  copy.id = 'TableA';

  /* you can change what you want already here, e.g: */
  [].forEach.call(copy.querySelectorAll('td'), function(item, index) {
    switch (item.textContent.trim()) {
      case 'Column 1':
        item.textContent = 'Column A';
        break;
      case 'Column 2':
        item.textContent = 'Column B';
        break;
      case 'Column 3':
        item.textContent = 'Column C';
        break;
    }
  });

  destination.parentNode.replaceChild(copy, destination);
}

function deleteTableB() {
  var tableB = document.getElementById('TableB');
  tableB.parentNode.removeChild(tableB);
}
```

```html
<button onclick="copytable()">Copy Table</button>
<button onclick="deleteTableB()">Delete TableB</button>

<br />
<br />

<table id="TableA">
  
</table>
<br />

<table id="TableB" style="border:solid">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <td id="col1">Column 1</td>
      <td id="col2">Column 2</td>
      <td id="col3">Column 3</td>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Data a</td>
      <td>Data b</td>
      <td>Data c</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<br />
```