# How to clone a whole table in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I tried to use cloneNode mentionned here [Copy the content of one table into another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/771571/copy-the-content-of-one-table-into-another) but Chrome says cloneNode is not a function

https://jsfiddle.net/4wczdykc/1/

```
<table>
    <thead>

        <tr>
            <th scope="col" colspan="1">TABLE TO CLONE</th>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <th>Column</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td></td>                         
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

script:

```
myTable = document.getElementsByTagName("Table")[0];
myClone = myTable.cloneNode(true);
document.body.appendChild(myClone);
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `getElementsByTagName()` method accesses all elements with the specified tagname.So you have to select the first element of the NodeList. So passed [0] to select it.

```
    myTable = document.getElementsByTagName("table")[0];
    myClone = myTable.cloneNode(true);
    document.body.appendChild(myClone);
```

[WORKING FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/4wczdykc/2/)